# Not showing all of my TextViews

Tags: java, android, xml

Well, I've got a `ListViewAdapter.java`, it looks like :

```
ListViewAdapter.java

public class ListViewItem {
    public final Drawable icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;       // the text for the ListView item title
    public final String precio;      // the price for the ListView item
    public final String descuento;   // the price for the discount for the ListView item
     // the text for the ListView item description

    public ListViewItem(Drawable icon, String title, String precio, String descuento) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;

        this.precio = precio;
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }
}
```

At the time that I create the ListView on my Fragment doesn't say nothing wrong... The code is :

```
 // initialize the items list
    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tomate_oferta), getString(R.string.aim), getString(R.string.aim_precio), getString(R.string.aim_descuento)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.levadura_oferta), getString(R.string.youtube), getString(R.string.youtube_precio), getString(R.string.youtube_descuento)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.sopa_oferta), getString(R.string.bebo), getString(R.string.bebo_precio), getString(R.string.bebo_descuento)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.zumo_oferta), getString(R.string.pew), getString(R.string.pew_precio), getString(R.string.pew_descuento)));

    // initialize and set the list adapter
    setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
}
```

And finally my xml looks like :

```
    ListViewItem.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the parent view - provides the gray background -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/frame_background"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/frame" >

        <!-- the icon view -->
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon_content_description"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <!-- the container view for the title and description -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <!-- the title view -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <!-- the description view -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDiscount"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListViewDemoAdapter.java

```
     public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDiscount.setText(item.descuento);
        viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(item.precio);


        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDiscount;
        TextView tvPrice;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

I don't get what I'm doing wrong... I thing the main problem is on the `XML`, but I don't see where.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: You don't tell any question... Tell us which are the TextViews that don't show. And how are them displayed in the device.

Comment: I said, It only shows the ImageView, tvTitle and tvPrice.

Comment: @PramodYadav My listViewDemoAdapter is on the post now.

Comment: post ur desired n current results image....

Comment: maybe because the other textviews have no text?

Comment: its because, you setting text to price and title textview.
You are not setting any text for discount textview niether dynamically nor in xml.

Comment: You are not setting this in your custom adapter class viewHolder.tvDiscount .setText(item.descuento);

Comment: I've edited the post because it still doing the same... There's an image of what I see on my App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem seems to be in Your layout_below attributes:

Every textView is set layout_below="@id/tvTitle", but with that every other textView is hidden by tvPrice. You have to change this like that:

```
     <!-- the title view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <!-- the description view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDiscount"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
```

### The second Problem:

In Your Adapter, You are referencing two views with the same id_

```
      viewHolder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
```

You have to change it to:

```
      viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
```

Comment: I'm seeing, and actually it does not work... it still showing only the Image, title and discount...

Comment: what happens? You wrote it works, have You changed something?

Comment: see my edit..maybe that is another issue. But the xml was definetely wrong, so just change it like I said.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 mistakes:

First is in layout, the tvprice and tvdiscount are overlapping as they are displayed one over the other.

```
        <!-- the description view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDiscount"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
```

Second is you are not setting the tv discount value:

```
    // update the item view
    ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
    viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(item.precio);
    viewHolder.tvDiscount.setText(item.descuento);
```

Another Problem is viewHolder.tvDiscount is pointing to tvPrice, correct as below:

```
viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
```

Comment: With the first mistake it's true, I was wrong, but the second one that was a Copy&Paste fail :P

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml to this.  Use  @+id/tvTitle instead of @id/tvTitle

```
<!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame" >

    <!-- the icon view -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <!-- the container view for the title and description -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <!-- the title view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <!-- the description view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDiscount"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I see you are still providing guess-based answers. Well, I'm still here to vote those down and provide justification for it (which you never do) : @+id/tvTitle will create a new id every time, it's completely wrong to use @+id in layout_below attributes. It COULD be used there only if you plan to define the View with tvTitle id after using it's id for positioning other views. Stop guessing and avoid down-votes ...

Comment: @2Dee ... finally someone who understands :)

Comment: What do you mean @2Dee

Comment: @Joan my comment was asked at Vivek. Don't use his answer (or any other answer he provides), its not the first time the answer he provides is just a guess, and a bad one, enforcing bad practices and misleading people...